# Wordpress Category/Tag Pages As Indexed Actually Help In Traffic?

Tags: seo, wordpress, duplicate-content

I several days ago somewhere read that category and tag pages should be noindexed. But later on somewhere else, I read that, they only increase rank for search term, but overall traffic decreases- said one from his experience.

So, if I just concern about traffic, not about individual search term that much, should I make those category and tag pages as indexed to google? I am confused which is the best to do.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Rana

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great post on the subject:

[No Indexing WordPress Taxonomies: Do or Don’t](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/no-indexing-wordpress-taxonomies-do-or-dont/49508/)

To summarise, he found that if he noindexed the tag and category archives and installed a better pagination plugin, his traffic increased by 30% in two weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Its one's personal experience. I saw similar opinion on the reverse case. So, I think we need more evidence to decide the right strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the rationale for using `noindex` on category and tag pages is that they *tend* to be near duplicates of each other and of the index page. Avoiding content duplication is a key aim of most SEO strategies. Thus the `noindex` approach.

As with most SEO questions, the best answer will come by thinking about what *people* want.

Do you have the sort of site, and the sort of content, where optimised archive pages for each of your categories would be a useful landing page *from search*? Or, are your category pages really just something that people use as a means of navigation when already on the site?

If it's the former, you need to design pages in such a way as to be well optimised for the category terms, e.g., with some unique editorial content and so on. If it's the latter, the typical WordPress template page with a `noindex` is probably best.

But don't trust me: trust your site. If you're really not sure what's best, experiment and let your analytics data guide you.